Why isn’t porphyria treated with ferrochelatase supplementation?
Erythropoietic protoporphyria (EPP) is a disorder characterized by ferrochelatase enzyme deficiency in all tissues.  Ferrochelatase puts the iron in protoporphyrin to make haem.
Other enzyme deficiencies such as lactose intolerance are treated with enzyme supplementation. Why is porphyria not treated with ferrochelatase supplementation?

Ferrochelatase is an enzyme found within cells, specifically in the mitochondria.
Lactase is a secreted enzyme, its function occurs outside cells (specifically, in the digestive cavity).
If you want to replace a secreted enzyme, the process is fairly simple: you just need to add it to the solution it would be secreted into. You can skip all the steps that came before secretion.
If you want to replace an internal enzyme, you would need to not just add it to the space outside of cells, you need some mechanism to get it inside cells. That's the hard part. Cells have complicated machinery for bringing specific molecules and ions into cells and keeping others out; that's pretty much the essence of all biology. For something that is normally produced internally and trafficked internally to where it needs to be, there is no already available machinery for getting that enzyme from outside the cell to inside the cell. If you were to build this machinery artificially, you'd still be stuck without a way to get your machinery into the cells in the first place.
Genetic engineering may be an alternative in some cases, I don't know if it's been studied with respect to this specific disorder. Viruses are an example of some machinery that can get things inside of cells that aren't normally supposed to be there; genetic engineering would involve using viral machinery to get DNA into a cell that contains the pattern required to produce a protein that is otherwise missing, so it can be assembled where it needs to be.
